Is energy and work the same in numerical basis?
Consider this formula:
P=W/t
where p is power, W is work, and t stands for time.
and also this formula:
E=Pt  ,
where E is energy, P is power, and t is time.
so by the substitution property, you can yield to:
E=(W/t) t ,
so as to say that the time will be canceled out, leading to:
E=W
Now, for my question, are energy and work quantitatively the same, not concerning thermodynamics alone, but retaining it as two different entities all the time? I am not asking what is the difference, but the formula suggests that work and energy are somewhat related quantitatively.
Thanks.

Generally speaking, no.
You should rather refer to change in energy $\Delta E$ rather than just "energy" $E$. Because work $W$ is a transfer of energy, and the energy some system has initially is independent of whatever work you do on it.
What the first law of thermodynamics says, is
\begin{equation}
\Delta E = Q + W \,,
\end{equation}
meaning that the energy of a system can change by exchanging either heat $Q$ or work $W$ with some other system. It is only in the case that $Q=0$ (i.e. systems don't exchange heat) that the change in energy equalts work $\Delta E=W$. This is typically the case, for example, in the adiabatic evolution of a gas, or in basic mechanics, where you only account for mechanical energy and no internal energy.

But isn't heat transfer just work done on a microscopic scale?

@BioPhysicist yes, totally. There are different descriptions you can do of identical physical systems. Say, you may describe an ideal gas macroscopically (in terms of pressure, volume, temperature, energy, etc) or microscopically (in terms of the position and velocity of each particle). In one description, there is work and heat transfer. In the other, only mechanical work (as long as gas particles have no internal degrees of freedom, such as molecular vibration). Both points of view are totally valid and more or less convenient in one or another context

Work is one of the ways to change a system's energy, but there are others (such as heating).
Since only changes in energy are relevant, the second equation would be better written as
$$\Delta E = Pt.$$
By the First Law, for a closed system,
$$\Delta E = Q+W,$$
where $Q$ represents heating. We can subdivide $P$ into $P_\mathrm{work}$ and $P_\mathrm{heating}$ and write
$$\Delta E = Pt = P_\mathrm{heating}t + P_\mathrm{work}t.$$
If heating is absent,
$$\Delta E = P_\mathrm{work}t=W.$$
In short, the change in energy equals the work if work is the only thing changing the internal energy - but it doesn't have to be.

But isn't heat transfer just work done on a microscopic scale?

At the single-particle scale, one can consider only individual particles doing work on each other, and heating ceases to have separate meaning. To clarify, my answer is not about that scale.
